# how to show sparse matrix with increasing data

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

how can we have the sparse matrix to be displayed in a way that the value part of a sparse matrix is increasing? I think by default, column part is increasing.

Comment: What is "the value part" of a sparse matrix? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: for example we have the matrix 'A' that its type is 'scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix' the values are the numbers when you parse A.data

Comment: With COO format, the print display order can be anything, depending how it was constructed.  For CSR, values are ordered by row.  Within the row, column indices may be unordered, though sorting is common.  There is a `sort_indices` method.  COO when converted to CSR sorts the indices lexically - rows, and columns within those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variation on the basic approach of sorting the `data`, and displaying the coordinates in the same order

First make a sample random matrix with integer values (for ease of display).  I'm using `coo` format because that's the one that shows the simplest relation between data and coordinates.

```
In [9]: M = (sparse.random(10,10,.1, 'coo')*10).astype(int)
In [10]: M
Out[10]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [11]: print(M)
  (1, 3)    1
  (3, 4)    7
  (5, 4)    1
  (7, 4)    8
  (5, 6)    9
  (6, 6)    7
  (5, 8)    4
  (6, 8)    1
  (4, 9)    5
  (9, 9)    1
```

In `ipython`, the basic display is the `repr` version, while `print` shows the `str` version.

Now get the sort order of the data:

```
In [12]: idx = np.argsort(M.data)
```

and make a new matrix with row and column in the same order:

```
In [13]: M1 = sparse.coo_matrix((M.data[idx],(M.row[idx], M.col[idx])),shape=M.shape)    
In [14]: M1
Out[14]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [15]: print(M1)
  (1, 3)    1
  (5, 4)    1
  (6, 8)    1
  (9, 9)    1
  (5, 8)    4
  (4, 9)    5
  (3, 4)    7
  (6, 6)    7
  (7, 4)    8
  (5, 6)    9
```

It's the same matrix, but the `data` array is sorted

```
In [16]: M.A
Out[16]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [17]: M1.A
Out[17]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [18]: M1.data
Out[18]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9])
```

Converting the coo to csr format requires sorting (lexical for row and col), so both coo matrices are converted in the same way:

```
In [19]: M.tocsr().data
Out[19]: array([1, 7, 5, 1, 9, 4, 7, 1, 8, 1], dtype=int32)
In [20]: M1.tocsr().data
Out[20]: array([1, 7, 5, 1, 9, 4, 7, 1, 8, 1], dtype=int32)
```

The cannonical csr order by rows and columns within those:

```
In [23]: print(M1.tocsr())
  (1, 3)    1
  (3, 4)    7
  (4, 9)    5
  (5, 4)    1
  (5, 6)    9
  (5, 8)    4
  (6, 6)    7
  (6, 8)    1
  (7, 4)    8
  (9, 9)    1
```

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward approach would be to "manually" sort the col/row indices by the value, using a [sorted(zip())](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-sort-two-lists-together-in-python) approach:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
m = csr_matrix([[0, 0, 7], [2, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0]])

print("As returned by csr:")
print(m)

print("Sorted by value:")
for d, r, c in sorted(zip(m.data, m.tocoo().row, m.tocoo().col)):
    print(f"  ({r}, {c})\t{d}")
```

which gives the following result:

```py
As returned by csr:
  (0, 2)    7
  (1, 0)    2
  (2, 1)    5
Sorted by value:
  (1, 0)    2
  (2, 1)    5
  (0, 2)    7
```